# Spring boot 3 - properties not getting loaded

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

- spring boot version 3.1.4
- spring.config.name=ondc
- spring.config.location=/home/my/project/config/
- running the jvm with following arguments
- config defined as

  - ondc.properties
  - ondc-local.properties

```
usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto/bin/java 

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000

 -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar ./build/libs/somejar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 

-Drun.arguments=
--spring.profiles.active=local,
--spring.config.name=ondc,
--spring.config.location=/home/my/project/config/

**Copy as single line** 
** new Line for presentation on SO **
```

ondc.properties

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------
# Http Client Config
#------------------------------------------------------------------
http.connpool.defaultKeepAliveTime=20000
http.client.connectionTimeout=10000
http.client.socketTimeout=20000
http.connpool.idleConnWaitTime=20000
http.connpool.maxconn=300
http.connpool.maxconnPerRoute=50
#------------------------------------------------------------------
# Mongo DB Connection Pooling
#------------------------------------------------------------------
spring.data.mongodb.database=dev
mongodb.app.db=dev
mongodb.auth.db=admin
mongodb.username=xxxx
mongodb.password=xxxx
mongodb.master.host=localhost
mongodb.master.port=27017
```

ondc-local.properties

```
does not contain anything
```

`spring.active.profiles=local` however its complaining about `mongodb` properties

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongodb.master.host' in value "${mongodb.master.host}"
```

Any clues ?

Even though I moved the mongo/http properties to ondc-local.properties still it could not resolve the properties.

`ConfigClass`

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MongoConfig extends MongoConfigurationSupport {

  @Value("${mongodb.master.host}")
  private String masterHost;...........
```

Eventhough I moved the mongo/http properties to ondc-local.properties still it could not resolve the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to read properties from the file system, you must append `file:` before the file path. so your property will become:

```
spring.config.location=file:/home/my/project/config/
```

alternatively, if your custom properties files were on classpath, then it would be specified as:

```
spring.config.location=classpath:/home/my/project/config/
```

Please note, If `spring.config.location` contains directories (as opposed to files) they should end in `/` (and will be appended with the names generated from **spring.config.name** before being loaded). The default search path `classpath:,classpath:/config,file:,file:config/` is always used, irrespective of the value of `spring.config.location`. In that way you can set up default values for your application in **application.properties** (or whatever other basename you choose with spring.config.name) and override it at runtime with a different file, keeping the defaults.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.2/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files